# How to negate substitution pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, ex-command

I've the following sample INI file:

```
Foo=1
Bar=1
Baz=1
Qux=1
```

and my goal is to set all options to 0 except `Foo`.

To disable one selected line, I know that I can run:

```
%s/Foo=\zs.*$/0/
```

Test command in shell:

```
$ ex +"%s/Foo=\zs.*$/0/p" -scwq file.ini
Foo=0
```

How can I negate substitution pattern, for example disabling every other option apart of `Foo`?

I'm also open for suggestions to use different commands instead to achieve the same result.

Comment: Does it have to be done with a substitute command? If you're OK using a different command, you could use global, e.g. `:g!/Foo/norm f=lC0`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, it can be different command as well. If you put it into the answer, it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:v`, e.g. something like this should work:

`:v/^Foo/s/.*=\zs\d$/0/g`